# If else statement is not working properly

Tags: java

This is a random number guessing game. My if/else statement does not work if I get the right answer. I would also want to give the user three chances to get the answer right. I am new to programming and not sure what to do. Any help appreciated.

```
package FinalProject;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a nickname");

        String name = s.nextLine();
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 15");

        int number = kbReader.nextInt();
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[1];

        for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
            arr[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 15);
            System.out.println("The number is:" + arr[x]);
            int i = 0;
            String quit;
            do {
                if (x == number) {
                    System.out.println("You win! " + name);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You lose " + name);
                }
                System.out.println("To quit the program enter q ");
                Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);
                quit = q.nextLine();

            } while (!quit.equals(("q")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to what "does not work" means?  What should happen, and what is happening instead?

Comment: Even if the number matches with the random one generated it says "You lose"

Comment: You don't have to create a new `Scanner` instance for every call to `nextLine()`. Just reuse `s`. EDIT: And close it with `s.close()` when you're done with it.

Comment: Why are you declaring an array of size 1?  Why not just not use an array?

Comment: But you aren't checking against the random number in your if statement, you're checking whether the guess equals the loop index.

Comment: and the loop index is always 0.

Comment: @mumpitz It is not good practice to close the `Scanner` that is declared with `System.in`, the JVM handles that and you would find yourself unable to ever open it during the execution of the program again (because you are closing `System.in` with it which was not opened by you).  `.close()` would used if reading from a file for example.

Comment: Furthermore the do/while loop around the win/lose check will just spin producing the same result until 'q' is entered, since no new random number is generated and nor does the user get to guess again.

Comment: I have to use an array and a loop for my project its a requirement

Comment: @Nexevis You are 100% right, this was a reflex reaction because one has to point this out so often. In this case, you shouldn't do it or at least be aware you are closing `stdin` for good.

Comment: and what you have to use the array for?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
if(arr[x] == number)
```

Instead of `if(x == number)` as here x is 0 which is not equal to your randomNumber whereas arr[x] can be.

Comment: For giving user three chances to get it right, try it if not. We are here to help. happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to much complicated.
I understand that you get one random number and you allow the user to guess it three times. Then if it is wrong, the user may quit or start a new game with a new random number and three more tries

Check the following code. I explain the most of the blocks below the code.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a nickname");
    String name = s.nextLine();

    while(true) {
        int tries=0;
        int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 15)+1; 
        while (tries < 3) {

            System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 15");
            int number = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
            if (randomNumber == number) {
                System.out.println("You win! " + name);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You lose " + name);
            }
            tries++;
        }
        System.out.println("The number is:" + randomNumber);
        System.out.println("To quit the program enter q ");
        String quit = s.nextLine();
        if ("q".equals(quit)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Generally, you can use one Scanner to read every user's input. As the nextInt reads until the next token, its better to read a line at once. Instead of nextInt() do a nextLine() and parse the String to int -> `int number = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());`

I cannot understand the use of an array, in my example I use the tries integer that is increased every time a guess is made. While loop runs until the tries is equal to 3, so the user has done tries 0,1,2 (3 tries).

The outer loop `while(true)` runs the game forever, until the user input is 'q' where that loop breaks and the game ends.

Inside the game's while loop, a randomNumber is taken from Math.random() and the user's input is validated in the if else for that specific input. Note that if you want to get a random number between 1-15 you should use `int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 15)+1;` as the Math.random() * 15 returns a random number between 0-14.

You dont want the game to ask for a next guess if the correct number is guessed, so add a `break;` after the 'You win' System.out. That way the inner loop is ended and the user is asked to quit or not.

If the tries is increased to 3, the game prints the correct number and asks the user to enter q to quit the program. You read the line and if 
`"q".equals(quit)` you break the outer loop and quit. If the user press any other text the outer loop continues, tries is set to 0, a new random number is taken and so on.

Updated: Code changed to support 3 guesses in one single random number and quit message after the 3 guesses are done incorrectly.

Output with 3 wrong guesses:

```
Enter a nickname
joe
Enter a number between 1 and 15
2
You lose joe
Enter a number between 1 and 15
3
You lose joe
Enter a number between 1 and 15
4
You lose joe
The number is:12
To quit the program enter q 
q
```

Output with a correct guess:

```
Enter a nickname
Joe
Enter a number between 1 and 15
1
You lose Joe
Enter a number between 1 and 15
2
You win! Joe
The number is:2
To quit the program enter q
```